# Java Project vs Maven Project (Eclipse), dir structure clarification needed

Tags: java, maven

When i create a new Maven project in Eclipse, directory structure contains both `src/main/java` and `src/main` (down below)

Question:
I understand my code should fall under `src/main/java`, what is the purpose of the `src/main`? Why does Eclipse create it?

[image]

Comment: How do you expect the `src/main/java` to exist without the `src/main`

Comment: Eclipse made it confusing .. one of "source folder", another is "folder"

Comment: @Manoj the image is pretty clear, its a legit question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For src/main/java to exist src/main/ must first exist so eclipse just shows you all the folders in your project including src/main/

If you want to remove them from your view in package explorer, you can create a filter for the package explorer view and exclude **Non-Java elements**.

Look for the down arrow in the top right of the package explorer view for the filters option.

Comment: Ok. Got it now. Was kind of weird to see "source folder" and "folders" with the same names, as Eclipse showed it

Answer (score 10):

`src/main/java` is Maven's standard layout for placement of your Java source codes.

Check http://java.sg/maven-standard-directory-layout/ for a list of standard Maven directories.

```
src/main/java       Application/Library sources
src/main/resources  Application/Library resources
src/main/filters    Resource filter files
src/main/assembly   Assembly descriptors
src/main/config     Configuration files
src/main/webapp     Web application sources
src/test/java       Test sources
src/test/resources  Test resources
src/test/filters    Test resource filter files
src/site        Site
LICENSE.txt     Project's license
NOTICE.txt      Notices and attributions required by libraries that the project depends on
README.txt      Project's readme
```

Comment: If this is a standard setting of Maven (and it is, you are correct, of course), then, why we have to look separately at both src/main/java and src/main folders in Eclipse? It is inconvenient and a waste of place.

Answer (score 3):

You can have other sub-directories under src/main that are not source files.
If you see Maven documentation you need to have resource files under src/main/resources.
Obviously the parent directory src/main needs to be created to create child directories.

Comment: And why have we to look at it? By the way, if you open it, it is empty.